# How to determine peer institutions?

Tags: university, education

Are there standard criteria to determine the peer institutions?

My institution is an american private liberal art university that follows the semester system, for which I can think of the following criteria:

1. Liberal art university
2. Private university
3. Semester-based university
4. Endowment of the university
5. Number of faculty in the department
6. Number of graduates with BS every 3 years say
7. Number of graduates with MS every 3 years say

Will that be OK? anything else?

Comment: Endowments may not be very useful in non-US institutions, which are often publicly funded.

Comment: I often hear the phrase "peer institution" used to mean an institution with which mine competes to attract students and faculty.  So it is often a question of the institutions (perceived) quality.

Answer (score 4):

[The Carnegie Foundation gives 6 types of criteria](http://carnegieclassifications.iu.edu/lookup_listings/standard.php):

1. Undergraduate instructional program
2. Graduate instructional program
3. Enrollment profile
4. Undergraduate profile
5. Size and setting
6. Basic classification

There are many factors involved--for instance, geographic region and percent of full time students are factors in 5 and 4.  I don't think semester versus quarter system is too important.  See the link for descriptions of these criteria.

There also seem to be a couple of Chronicle articles about selecting peer institutions:

http://chronicle.com/article/in-selecting-peers/134228/

http://chronicle.com/article/Who-Does-Your-College-Think/134222/

however I can't access the Chronicle website right now, but did find this other article which discusses the first Chronicle article linked:

http://theairspace.net/commentary/u-s-colleges-name-their-own-peer-institutions-rank-themselves/